# $\bigcup_{x\in K}B'(x,r)=\left \{x\in X |d(x,K)\leq r\right \}$ for $K$ compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $K$ be a compact subset of $X$

Let $r>0$ be given

Prove, $\bigcup_{x\in K}B'(x,r)=\left \{x\in X |d(x,K)\leq  r\right \}$ where $d(x,K)=inf_{y\in K}d(x,y)$ (B' is closed ball)

Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$1).\ $ If $y\in \bigcup_{x\in K}B'(x,r),$ then $y\in B'(x,r)$ for some ball $B'$. Then, $d(x,y)\le r.$

$2).\ $ If $y\in \left \{x\in X |d(x,K)\leq  r\right \},\ $ then fix this $y$ and note that the function $d(y,\cdot ):X\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, so it attains its minimum on the compact set $K$.

Comment: I'm done with 1) , I found my way with the first inclusion,but I'm stuck with 2)

Comment: The key phrase is: " it attains its minimum on the compact set K."

Comment: You mean inf(d(y,K))=<d(y,K) ?

Comment: I mean the inf is reached. So now that means that there is a ___ in ___ such that ___.

Comment: There is a sequence in K that converges ??

Comment: Since $d(y,K)\le r$, there is a point $x\in K$ such that $d(y,x)\le r$ and this says that $y\in B'(x,r).$

Comment: If $K$ is compact then for every $y$ there is an $x \in K$ such that $d(x,y)=d(y,K)$.

Comment: Yes. Typo. Thanks-

Comment: I guess the statement should be in fact: $d(y,K)=s\le r$, so there is an $x\in $K$ s.t. $d(y,x)=s$.